# How to travel from Cincinnati to O'Hare

Tags: usa, public-transport, airport-transfer, ord, ohio

What is the cheapest and quickest solution for traveling from Cincinnati Ohio to Chicago O'Hare early Friday and returning Tuesday afternoon?

Answer (score 6):

Today, for leaving April 29 and returning May 3:

The quickest is a CVG-ORD flight, which is $452 round trip.

Cheaper is Amtrak, which starts at $98 round trip. In both directions this train runs overnight.

Cheaper still is Megabus, which will be $44 round trip if you buy right this minute, and will go up if you wait. (And thanks to Karlson for the reminder!)

For cheapest of all, drive yourself. It's only 300 miles each way, and gas is cheap in Indiana.

Comment: +1 for driving. 300 miles is well within the 1-tank limit of most cars. An average small car has a 12 gallon tank; the cheapest gas in Cincinnati is around 1.89, which leads to approx $23 to fill the car; for a bigger car lets say 16 gallon tank; $30 approx. If you were to rent the car, average car rental prices in Cincinnati are from [$13 - $33 per day](https://www.kayak.com/Cheap-Cincinnati-Car-Rentals.22335.cars.ksp), and you are given a car with a full tank of gas. If you were to rent a car and drive it yourself, it would cost a little more than the train, but a lot faster.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Michael's answer you can use buses:

- [Megabus](http://www.megabus.com) - $35
- [Greyhound](http://www.greyhound.com) - about $50 Round Trip

And in Chicago you can use Chicago public transportation to get to O'Hare.